# Update customer attributes of old module

Tags: module, upgrade, ce-1.8.0.0

I have an old module and I need to update it so it will work with a newer Magento version. Basically the module adds some customer fields.

So there a `config.xml` like this:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <DWI_Customer>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
        </DWI_Customer>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <fieldsets>
            <customer_account>
                <membernumber><create>1</create><update>1</update></membernumber>
                ...
            </customer_account>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```

Notice there is no resources setup config defined but stilll there is a `Entity/Setup.php`

```
class DWI_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{
    public function getDefaultEntities()
    {
        return array(
            'customer' => array(
                'entity_model'          =>'customer/customer',
                'table'                 => 'customer/entity',
                'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
                'increment_per_store'   => false,
                'additional_attribute_table' => 'customer/eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection' => 'customer/eav_attribute',
                'attributes' => array(
            'membernumber' => array(
            'label'     => 'Member No',
            'visible'   => true,
                        'sort_order'    => 65,
        ),
            ....
        );
    }
}
```

With newer version those fields are not visible (but added to `eav_attribute`) and I need to add an upgrade script like this:

```
$config->getAttribute('customer', 'membernumber' )
    ->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) )
    ->save();
```

I did the with other modules and it worked fine. Problem here is I don't have `sql/customer_setup/mysql4....` here. Also it looks like the module does not show up in `core_resource` or I am not sure how it would be named. `customer_setup` feels right but that is already been used by Mage/Customer.

Question is: **How do I add an upgrade script for this module?**

Comment: Name your resource node `dwi_customer_setup`. and put the upgrade scripts in `sql/dwi_customer_setup`.

Comment: You put the `resources` tag inside the `fieldsets`. Move it one level higher

Comment: @Marius Thanks for you help. That worked! Can you post your comments as an answer so I can give you the bounty. Would be a waste otherwise ;)

Comment: Done. Yey.. for bounty points :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the install script using the resource name `dwi_customer_setup`. In this case the upgrade scripts go under inside the folder `sql/dwi_customer_setup` of your extension.
This way you avoid the collision with the `customer_setup` resource.

In `config.xml` add the  tag and changed version to 1.0.2.:

```
<global>
     <resources>
         <dwi_customer_setup>
             <setup>
                 <module>DWI_Customer</module>
             </setup>
         </dwi_customer_setup>
     </resources>
    ...
</global>
```

create `DWI\Customer\sql\dwi_customer_setup\upgrade-1.0.1-1.0.2.php` with

```
<?php

$this->startSetup();

Mage::getSingleton( 'eav/config' )
->getAttribute( 'customer', 'membernumber' )
->setData( 'used_in_forms', array( 'adminhtml_customer' ) )
->save();

$this->endSetup();
```

And very important as always: Clear your cache!

Comment: I feel kind of dirty for this answer. I only provided some suggestions. @PiTheNumber did the coding.